# Color Grid Cell in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: colors, grid, windows-phone-8.1

I'm looking for a way of coloring a cell in a grid in xaml wp 8.1. Is this possible or not ? 
I don't want to insert a rectangle control into the cell in order to color it as it can be done that way...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid itself supports a background color only for the whole thing, not for individual rows or columns.

The only way to color individual cells (row/column combinations) in a WP8.1 Xaml Grid is to put a colored element in the cell. A border is probably better than a rectangle, assuming that you want some other content inside the colored cell.